# computing sampling rate of gps

Tags: sql, postgresql, statistics, aggregate-functions

As I follow up to my question (deleted), I can confirm the description of sampling rate I am looking to calculate. The sampling is with regards to the gps points per trip. My table looks like this (actually I should call the last column sampling interval NOT rate):

```
SELECT * FROM trajectories_splitted LIMIT 10;
 user_id |   session_id   |       timestamp        |    lat    |    lon     | alt | sampling_rate | rate_diff 
---------+----------------+------------------------+-----------+------------+-----+---------------+-----------
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:04+01 | 39.984702 | 116.318417 | 492 |               |          
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:10+01 | 39.984683 |  116.31845 | 492 | 00:00:06      |         6
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:15+01 | 39.984686 | 116.318417 | 492 | 00:00:05      |         5
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:20+01 | 39.984688 | 116.318385 | 492 | 00:00:05      |         5
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:25+01 | 39.984655 | 116.318263 | 492 | 00:00:05      |         5
       1 | 20081023025304 | 2008-10-23 02:53:30+01 | 39.984611 | 116.318026 | 493 | 00:00:05      |         5
       1 | 20081023025305 | 2008-10-23 04:08:07+01 | 39.995777 | 116.286798 | 716 |               |          
       1 | 20081023025305 | 2008-10-23 04:08:12+01 | 39.996832 | 116.285446 | 276 | 00:00:05      |         5
       1 | 20081023025305 | 2008-10-23 04:08:42+01 | 39.984397 | 116.299292 | 931 | 00:00:30      |        30
       1 | 20081023025305 | 2008-10-23 04:08:47+01 | 39.984426 | 116.299329 | 959 | 00:00:05      |         5
       1 | 20081023025305 | 2008-10-23 04:08:52+01 | 39.984499 | 116.299413 | 983 | 00:00:05      |         5
       1 | 20081023025305 | 2008-10-23 04:08:57+01 | 39.984424 | 116.299467 | 990 | 00:00:05      |         5
       1 | 20081023025305 | 2008-10-23 04:09:02+01 |  39.98441 | 116.299477 | 940 | 00:00:05      |         5
       1 | 20081023025305 | 2008-10-23 04:09:07+01 | 39.984421 | 116.299569 | 928 | 00:00:05      |         5
       1 | 20081023025305 | 2008-10-23 04:09:12+01 | 39.984518 |  116.29953 | 902 | 00:00:05      |         5
       1 | 20081023025305 | 2008-10-23 04:09:17+01 | 39.984488 | 116.299645 | 897 | 00:00:05      |         5
```

This shows the gps traces of two trips: `20081023025304` and `20081023025305`.

To calculate the sampling rate for a trip, I should do:

[image]

for that trip, repeating this get the value for each trip (which I can then plot).

For that I need access to the first and last `timestamp` for each trip (where `session_id` represents unique trip). so for example in the case of trip `20081023025305` above, the sampling rate would be:

[image]

i.e. number of points-1/duration. I am not sure if  `LEAD/LAG` functions could be used in this case to get first last/first `timestamp` for each trip.

**EDIT**

I would like to get something like:

```
+----------------+---------------+
|   session_id   | sampling_rate |
+----------------+---------------+
| 20081023025304 | 0.1923        |
| 20081023025305 | 0.1286        |
+----------------+---------------+
```

For `20081023025304` is `6points -1 /26 secs` and for `20081023025305` is `10points - 1 / 70 secs`.

2. Maybe better to say the `rate = totalPoints -1 / sum(rate_diff)` for that trip.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to ask a specific question. It's not clear what you need.

Comment: question edited to clarify the point.

Comment: Please post formulas as text instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty simple:

```
select session_id,
       count(*) / nullif((max(timestamp) - min(timestamp), 0) as sampling_rate
from trajectories_splitted
group by session_id;
```

Comment: First time to see this function(`nullif`) I should just switch the the expression, to have duration as the denominator.

Comment: @super_ask . . . I fixed the logic.  Sampling rate, sampling frequency -- its all the same thing really.  That said, the purpose of `nullif()` is to avoid a divide by zero error.